# Issue with deserialization when an avro schema is composed of another schema as an optional field

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

we have defined an avro schema and using code generators to generate .java files in Java and .cs files C#.

Here is the code generator we have been using to generate java classes out of the avro schema

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro

and using AvroConverter.exe (from Confluen)  to generate .cs files from .avsc file

Now, I'm trying to use publish a message onto Kafka using a c# producer and trying to consume it using a java consumer. This is working for most of the data type except the below contract "OptionalComposition".

The deserialization is failing only for an optional field ( another schema)

```
{
 "type": "record",
 "name": "OptionalComposition",
 "doc": "Contract to test composition with optional field ",
 "namespace": "com.abc.avro.contracts",
 "fields": [
{ "name": "partOf", "type": ["null", "com.abc.avro.contracts.Reference"], "default": null }
]
 }
```

```
{
 "type": "record",
 "name": "Reference",
 "namespace": "com.abc.avro.contracts",
 "fields": [
{ "name": "identifier", "type": "string" }
,
{ "name": "name", "type": "string" }
]
 }
```

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to java.lang.String - this is the error I'm getting

Comment: That doesn't say anything about your Reference class. Can you show your Java code and generated class? Also, the maven plugin has a setting to convert utf8 to string classes, maybe Gradle has the same

Comment: this is the gradle plugin we are using to generate .Java files from .avsc files and I'm able to resolve the issue by specifying the an extra parameter avro {
    stringType = "CharSequence"
} https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to resolve this issue by setting an extra property (stringType to "CharSequence") with my gradle plug-in to generate my .java files out of .avsc files.

Here is the link of the gradle plug-in we are using to generate .java files out of .avsc files

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro

Here is the documentation of the property I'm talking about
https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin#stringtype

Here is my gradle task to generate the POJOs out of .avsc files

```
task generateContracts(type: GenerateAvroJavaTask, dependsOn: clearContracts) {
    fieldVisibility = "PRIVATE"
    dateTimeLogicalType = 'JSR310'
    outputCharacterEncoding = "UTF-8"
    stringType = "CharSequence"
    source("src/main/resources/avro")
    outputDir = file("src/main/java/")
}
```

By adding stringType = "CharSequence", we are asking the code generator to
generate String type properties to have java.lang.CharSequence as the data type instead of java.lang.String